# Set label format in time-of-day histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bunch of timestamps and want to make a histogram of the time-of-day value:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mydata <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mobilizingcs/demo/gh-pages/data/snack/snackdemo.csv")
time_of_day <- strptime(substring(mydata$context.timestamp, 12), format = "%H:%M:%S")

# Almost right
qplot(time_of_day)
```

[image: plot1]

The default is almost what I want, but I want the labels of X to only show the time, not the date:

```
# This seems wrong??
qplot(time_of_day) + scale_x_datetime(labels = scales::date_format("%H:%M"))
```

[image]

Now I am indeed getting the label format, but ggplot2 seems to put the wrong label values? It is labeling the point `16 Sept 00:00` as `22:00` in the new plot. How do I get the original scale, but with the `%H:%M` label format?

Comment: Use the tz, see if it changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scales::date_format` by default is setting `tz = "UTC"` which results in the wrong time.

looking at `time_of_day` you want *CEST*-Timezone so the following works

```
qplot(time_of_day) + 
    scale_x_datetime(labels = scales::date_format("%H:%M", tz = "Europe/Berlin"))
```

Edit: If you do not want to rely on the user's timezone you have to specify the tz of `mydata$context.timestamp` first.
Specifically your `strptime` call results in different times depending on the users current tz. See `?strptime`. As you do not supply a tz, the default is `tz=""`

> but "" is the current time zone

Solution:

1. Specify the data of `mydata$context.timestamp` within `strptime`
2. Pick a "standard" timezone that you want to plot your data in and supply this to `scales::date_format("%H:%M", tz="YOUR STANDART TZ")`

As most standardisation choose  `tz = "UTC"` this is the default in `scales::date_format`

Answer (score 0):

See, I'm getting a totally different graph here on the east coast:

[image: My graph]

I've dug into the ggplot2 source code and found...well, honestly it's too deeply functional for me to understand all of it ;p. But I suspect the cause, given the differing results we're seeing betwixt our platforms, is that at some point scale_x_datetime is making assumptions about the timezones the data is in that aren't born out by the actual data. That's all I've got. Seems like a bug.